# JDeveloper 11 and ADF - change the page DTD to HTML5

Tags: html, weblogic, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have an Oracle ADF / WebLogic project built by someone else with JDeveloper 11 (and the integrated WL server).

The problem is that the HTML DTD is outputted as:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

and I want to change it to HTML5 mode, and I don't know how (I'm a front-end developer):

```
<!doctype html>
```

The pages start with this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">

  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>

  <f:view>

    <af:document id="d1">
....
```

Has anyone done this in JDev 11? I couldn't find the answer anywhere. Some people say that JDev 12 does it, but I'm not sure if I can import and build the project in v12 without a lot of changes.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, JDeveloper 12c uses HTML5, so an upgrade it will help.

I am not aware of any way of changing the doc type in ADF, but you can hack it by altering html response using Servlet Filter:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html

Comment: Can you spare 5 minutes with a more concrete example? I am a front-end developer, not at all familiar with ADF, and the example is very generic and incomplete.

Comment: You may find this example useful: http://jonasdegraaff.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/how-to-run-your-adf-111x-application.html . There is a sample project with it, although the sample is altering the header, the concept is the same, I guess.

Comment: Tried it, it's a whole other thing, as the meta entries are inside the <html>, whereas the DTD is outside everything. Still looking for a solution.

Comment: I think this solution would intercept the entire response sent to the browser, therefore DTD info as well. If you have a sample  I could run myself locally, I would be more than happy to have a look.